# hardstatus screen in mac

Tags: macos, mac, display, gnu-screen

I use this hardstatus in my .screenrc

hardstatus string '%{= kK}[ %h ] %-Lw%{= KW}%50>%n%f %t%{= kK}%+Lw%< %{=kG}%-= %1` %d %M %c%{-}%{= kK}   '

but in macOS the %h not work, don't show the hostname.
Any idea ? 
many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a screenrc (host-level, not personal) configuration issue.

I see the same behavior on my OS X 10.6 (snow leopard) machine with the screen that comes installed with OS X (located in /usr/bin/screen).

I then installed screen from [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and the `%h` tracked the changes to my Terminal window title bar as you desire.

They look like they're essentially the same version, but I notice that there is no global screenrc file in `/etc/screenrc` (where I would expect to find it for the `/usr/bin/screen` version) and there is a file in `/opt/local/etc/screenrc` which has a bunch of termcap and terminfo commands. My guess is that somwhere in here is the magic which allows screen to follow the changes to the title bar and thus the changes for `%h`.

You have two options:

- Install screen from MacPorts (`sudo port install screen` -- assuming, of course, that you already have the core MacPorts installed)
- Ask nicely for the `/opt/local/etc/screenrc` file which MacPorts installed. Try putting it into `/etc/screenrc` and see if it works. (I put the copy from my machine in [this paste bin site entry](http://dpaste.com/170966/). It will be there for about 30 days before it's autodeleted)

Comment: I compiled from source, but the problem persists

Comment: Did the version you built install a non-empty /etc/screenrc file?

Comment: ... or where ever your compiled version of screen expects the global screenrc to live. You can determine this by looking at the output of `strings /path/to/screen | grep screenrc`. /usr/bin/screen shows "/private/etc/screenrc"

Answer (score 0):

Try `%H`:

```
hardstatus string '%{= kK}[ %H ] %-Lw%{= KW}%50>%n%f %t%{= kK}%+Lw%< %{=kG}%-= %1` %d %M %c%{-}%{= kK} '
```

Comment: yes, I try with H, but hostname not change in a ssh conection how to in linux.

Comment: Oh, you want it to change when you SSH into a new system? I don't think that's possible. I could be wrong.

Comment: with "%h" this is posible, I tested in a debian

Comment: Wow. I didn't know it would do that. Pretty cool.